# No virtual methods newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;) issue when generating build

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I have been using `retrofit2` along with `Gson` convertor in many applications. But currently I'm contributing to an existing project and i have used both dependencies. While running the project directly, it works perfectly. But whenever I generate a `debug` or `release` build, This error appears in Toast and `Api` content is not parsed.

Proguard is disabled. Here is the error:

> No virtual method
>   newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonReader; in
>   class Lcom/google/gson/Gson; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.gson.Gson' appears in
>   /data/app/com."packagename"/base.apk:classes2.dex)

**App Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.medris.medrisemt.medrishcemt"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
}

    repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':zoomsdk')
    implementation project(':zoomcommonlib')
    implementation project(':redirectionalgorithm');

androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have searched for relevant answers but no satisfactory results. I have tried to downgrade the gson & retrofit dependencies but no success.

**Update**

I have updated the `Gson` & `retrofit-convertor` dependencies in the gradle code above to the one I was actually using initially. I mistakenly posted the downgraded ones that I tried for testing.

Comment: Why are you toasting errors?

Comment: I'm not toasting errors. Since this error appears only when a generated debug or release build is used, it appears on its own.

Comment: Okay. Your question says *This error appears in Toast and Api content is not parsed*

Comment: Did anyone solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

I started using the newer versions:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

And the error disappeared.

> After adding this dependencies in your gradle file, please clean and
>   rebuild your project.

Comment: I have been using the latest dependency earlier: `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'` When I faced the issue, I downgraded it to **2.6** but still the issue persists.

I have already tried cleaning, rebuilding & even clearing the cache. What surprises me is that why the error doesn't appear by running it directly on a real device from android studio.

Answer (score 0):

**write this in build.gradle > these are newer versions**

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

Comment: I have been using the latest dependency earlier: 
`implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'`

When I faced the issue, I downgraded it to **2.6** but still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit too late but I am sharing my experience. I also ran into the same issue and updating the gson library did not fix it. This error only happened on some asian unknown phone with android 8.1. The only solution that worked for me was to replace this library with kotlin serialization:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter

This is still updated, specially designed for kotlin (with gson isn't) and extremely stable and versatile (in my experience). Switch to this and be care free.